# Recursive sequence $a_n=(3a_{n-1}+1+\sqrt{12a_{n-1}+1})/3$

Tags: recurrence-relations

> Given $a_0=0$, $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{3a_{n-1}+1+\sqrt{12a_{n-1}+1}}{3}$, find $a_n$ in terms of $n$.

By finding the first few terms of $a$, I get a pattern and deduce that $a_n=n(n+1)/3$. I wonder if these's method to find $a_n$ without guessing its pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Put $x_n = \sqrt{12a_n+1}$ for every $n$. The recurrence relation can be simplified to $x_n = x_{n-1}+2$.